# Не могу разобраться с кодировкой

Tags: python, linux, windows, paramiko

Пишу на windows в  VS code, версия python 3.6.8.
Хочу получить список папок и файлов по SSH (на Linux).

Пишу такой код:

```
import paramiko 

host = '192.168.0.8'
user = 'login'
secret = 'password'
port = 22

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
Print(data)
client.close()
```

Выводит \X32\X03\X62 и т.д. Как я понял это юникод, но не понимаю как с эти бороться.

Comment: Кодировку указать где-нибудь

Comment: Да это понятно, но какую и как указать?

Comment: Ssh умеет передавать переменные окружения, такие как LC_*, LANG и прочие. Оттуда и берите. Локальную, соответственно из локальных.

Comment: а что такое `Print ()`? или просто опечатка?

Comment: А в выводе буквы X точно заглавные? Похоже на байтовую строку, но у неё обычно маленькие x бывают.

Answer (score 0):

можете попробовать альтернативный способ получения списка папок и файлов в директории при помощи [STPClient().listdir()](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir)

```
import paramiko

host = '192.168.0.8'
user = 'login'
secret = 'password'
port = 22
with paramiko.SSHClient() as client:
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port)
    client_ssh = client.open_sftp()
    text_content = client_ssh.listdir()
    print(text_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Выводит \X32\X03\X62/ . Как я понял это юникод

Это НЕ юникод. Если предположить, что это ТЕКСТОВАЯ строка, то первый символ - '2', а вот второй - непечатыемый ASCII символ ETX. Если бы это были два байта юникода, то в первом байте был бы код, больше, чем 0x77. Вот как выглядят буквы кирилицы 'абвг' в юникоде:

```
 D0 B0   D0 B1   D0 B2   D0 B3
   а       б       в       г
```

Так что то, что Вы продемонстрировали, это (скорее всего) - просто двоичные данные какие-то. Откуда они взялись - это знаете только Вы.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Разобрался в проблеме сам. Использовал:

```
data.decode("utf-8")
```

и получил читаемый вывод